How to generate all possible combinations subject to symmetry conditions
I have a list of 6 (possibly repeated) integers:
ints = {a,b,c,d,e,f};

and also a set of symmetry conditions:

You can switch the signs of elements 1 and 4 at the same time:
$$
\{a,b,c,d,e,f\} \equiv \{-a,b,c,-d,e,f\}
$$

You can switch any of the pairs of elements (1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6) with another one


$$
\{a,b,c,d,e,f\} \equiv \{a,c,b,d,f,e\} \equiv \{b,a,c,e,d,f\} \equiv \{b,c,a,e,f,d\} \equiv \{c,a,b,f,d,e\} \equiv \{c,b,a,f,e,d\}
$$

The first three elements and the last 3 elements can be switched
$$
\{a,b,c,d,e,f\} \equiv \{d,e,f,a,b,c\}
$$

I want to write a function F[{a,b,c,d,e,f}] which would produce all (unrepeated) sets which can be generated from the argument via repeated application of the symmetries.
For example:
F[{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}] = {{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

and
F[{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

and
F[{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0}] = {{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1}, {-1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1}, {-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1}, {0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1}, {0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1}, {0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1}, {0, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1}, {0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1}, {1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0}, {1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1}, {1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1}, {1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}}


Start by consulting PermutationGroup:  https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PermutationGroup.html?q=PermutationGroup

I do not think there could be any shortcut to get the result other than brute-force.

The first argument is identity permutation. The second argument is list of rules/permutations and the third argument is an expression on which the function is applied.
fu[x_, rules_, expr_] := Block[{out = {expr}, new},
  
  While[new = 
    Complement[Flatten[rules /. Thread[x -> #] & /@ out, 1], out]; 
   out = Join[out, new]; new != {}];
  out
  ]

So for the three examples we have:
rules = {{-a, b, c, -d, e, f}, {a, c, b, d, f, e}, {b, a, c, e, d, 
    f}, {b, c, a, e, f, d}, {c, a, b, f, d, e}, {c, b, a, f, e, 
    d}, {d, e, f, a, b, c}};

fu[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, rules, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}]
Length[%]

fu[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, rules, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
Length[%]

fu[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, rules, {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0}]
Length[%]


{{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, -1,
   1}, {-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1, 1, 
  1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}

8

{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

1

{{-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, -1}, {-1, -1, -1, 
  0, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1,
   1, -1, 0, 1}, {-1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1}, {-1, 
  1, -1, -1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, -1, 0, 
  1, -1}, {0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1,
   1, 0, -1}, {1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1}, {-1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 
  1, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1}, {-1, 1, 0, -1, 
  1, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1}, {0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1}, {0, 
  1, -1, -1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1}, {1, -1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 
  0, -1, 1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1, 0, 1, -1}, {1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 
  0}, {-1, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1, 
  0, 1}, {-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 0}, {-1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, -1, 1, 1, -1, 
  1}, {0, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1}, {1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 
  1}, {1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, -1}, {-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 
  1}, {-1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 0, 1, -1, 
  1}, {1, 0, -1, 1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
  1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 
  1, 0, 1, 1, 1}}

48

